# Odds of "at least m" and "exactly m" occurrences of an event from multiple ones

Tags: probability

We have the probability of having a certain output $X$ for each of $20$ given mutually exclusive events. How to calculate the odds of "at least $m$" of them being $X$ (for $m$ between $1$ to $20$)?
How about the odds of "exactly $m$" of those events being $X$?

EDIT (clarity):

Let's say we have 20 experiments, each of which has 20% chance to win (between win and fail, as the only two outcomes). What are the odds that in this 20 experiments, we have exactly one win, two wins, ... 20 wins? Similarly for "at least" one win, etc

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Do you mean that, on any given trial, we might get one of $20$ mutually exclusive events and then, for each of those events, we might get any of several outputs, one of which is $X$?

Comment: To clarify:  for instance, a trial might consist of reaching into a bag which contains $20$ dice, each of which has a separate weighting system.  You could then ask for the probability that you roll a $6$ with the die you extract.  Fair question, but to answer it you would need to know the probability of extracting a particular die (in my example that would be uniform, so $\frac 1{20}$, but that doesn't have to be the case) and then you need the probability distributions for the possible outcomes of each of the possible dice.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As it stands it doesn't make much sense.  I've tried to guess at a meaning, but I almost certainly got it wrong.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Let's say we have 20 experiments, each of which has 20% chance to win (between win and fail, as the only two outcomes). What are the odds that in this 20 experiments, we have exactly one win, two win, ... 20 win? Similarly for "at least" one win, etc.

Comment: Does that make sense now @lulu?

Comment: In general, you want a binomial distribution. If you're just looking for numbers for a specific use case, a binomial calculator such as http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx might be of use (for the example above, set the probability of success to "0.2", the number of trials to "20", and the number of successes to whatever value you're interested in).

Comment: That's helpful, but I need to know how to get to the results. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a binomial distribution. If you have $n$ experiments, each with a probability $p$ of success, the probability of getting exactly $k$ successes is

$$\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)n^k$$

where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

For the cumulative probability of $k$ or more successes, you just need the sum of these values from $k, k+1, ...$ up to $n$.

For more information, the Wikipedia page for the binomial distribution is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution